# Error: Merge -Tag can't work with fragement in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, viewgroup

I used a Merge -Tag for a my class extend Fragement. But I met error when I was trying to access elements of R class.

My logcat shows: "android.view.InflateException:  can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true" .
Bellow is my `source code`. Please help me. I sorry about my english, it is not good.

```
public class DetailHeader extends Fragment {
ImageView imageView;
TextView textHeader;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     LinearLayout wrapper = new LinearLayout(getActivity()); // for example
     inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_header, wrapper, true);
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_header, null);
     imageView =(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
     textHeader =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewHeader);
     imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dengiong);
     return wrapper;
     }
}
```

This is my `xml file`:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:padding="12dip"
    android:text="Golden Gate"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

</merge>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `<merge>` tag as your root view in a layout, that layout can only be used via `<include>` from another layout.  Otherwise your inflated layout has no root `ViewGroup` in which to hold the child views (in your case the `ImageView` and `TextView`.)  So you need to replace the `<merge>` with a real `ViewGroup` instance, such as `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout`.